# Submit sparkR job to remote cluster - Task failed while writing rows

Tags: apache-spark, hdfs, hadoop-yarn, sparkr

When I use `spark-submit` to run a sparkR job on a remote Spark cluster that uses YARN, the job appears to succeed but the logs show that a task failed when attempting to write the results data frame to a json file in HSFS. If the sparkR script is run directly from a gateway machine in the cluster the job succeeds and is able to write the data to the file.

The relevant warning is:

```
WARN scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 8.0 (TID 16, hadoop5.lavastorm.com): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task failed while writing rows.
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DefaultWriterContainer.writeRows(WriterContainer.scala:251)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3.apply(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.scala:150)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3.apply(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.scala:150)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:88)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: scala.MatchError: [1,null,null,[2.62]] (of class org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericMutableRow)
at org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.VectorUDT.serialize(Vectors.scala:194)
at org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.VectorUDT.serialize(Vectors.scala:179)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.json.JacksonGenerator$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$json$JacksonGenerator$$valWriter$2$1.apply(JacksonGenerator.scala:103)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.json.JacksonGenerator$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$json$JacksonGenerator$$valWriter$2$1.apply(JacksonGenerator.scala:89)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.json.JacksonGenerator$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$json$JacksonGenerator$$valWriter$2$1.apply(JacksonGenerator.scala:126)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.json.JacksonGenerator$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$json$JacksonGenerator$$valWriter$2$1.apply(JacksonGenerator.scala:89)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.json.JacksonGenerator$.apply(JacksonGenerator.scala:133)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.json.JsonOutputWriter.writeInternal(JSONRelation.scala:185)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DefaultWriterContainer.writeRows(WriterContainer.scala:243)
... 8 more
```

There is a difference between the two cases in the information earlier in the log as it shows two users in the acl when the job is submitted remotely. The yarn user is not in the acl when the job is submitted locally:

```
INFO spark.SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: yarn,lavastorm
INFO spark.SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: yarn,lavastorm
```

Thanks in advance for any pointers towards the root cause.

// Update
The following additional log text indicates the job eventually failed:

```
ERROR datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation: Aborting job. org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 1 in stage 8.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 1.3 in stage 8.0 (TID 23, hadoop5.lavastorm.com): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task failed while writing rows.
```

The directory for the json results file is being created but there are no 'part-r-0000..' files (or '_SUCCESS' file) created in the directory.

The SparkR script being submitted is:

```
Sys.setenv(HADOOP_CONF_DIR='/etc/hadoop/conf')
Sys.setenv(YARN_CONF_DIR='/etc/hadoop/conf')
Sys.setenv(JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle-cloudera")

.libPaths(c("/usr/lib/spark/R/lib", .libPaths()))

library(SparkR)

sc <- sparkR.init(appName = 'SparkR-mtcars-Predict-LinReg',
                  sparkEnvir = list(spark.driver.memory="2g",
                                    spark.executor.cores='2',
                                    spark.executor.instances='2'))

sqlContext <- sparkRSQL.init(sc)

trainFP <- "hdfs://hadoop5.lavastorm.com:8020/user/lavastorm/mtcars.json"
UnseenFP <- "hdfs://hadoop5.lavastorm.com:8020/user/lavastorm/mtcars_wt.json"
trainDF <- jsonFile(sqlContext, trainFP)
UnseenDF <- jsonFile(sqlContext, UnseenFP)

model <- glm(mpg ~ wt, family = "gaussian", trainDF)
predicted <- predict(model, UnseenDF)

targetFP <- "hdfs://hadoop5.lavastorm.com:8020/user/lavastorm/mtcars_predictions.json"
write.df(predicted, targetFP, "json", mode = "overwrite")

sparkR.stop()
```

Comment: Maybe the application don´t response exit(-1) and then job is ok. Line of error is a WARN.